# NHibernate: Object hierarchy and performance

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I've a database with a Customer table. Each of these customers has a foreign key to an *Installation* table, which further has an foreign key to an *Address* table (table renamed for simplicity).

In *NHibernate* I'm trying to query the Customer table like this:

```
ISession session = tx.Session;
var customers = session.QueryOver<Customer>().Where(x => x.Country == country);                               
var installations = customers.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Installation, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
var addresses = installations.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Address, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

if (installationType != null)
{
    installations.Where(x => x.Type == installationType);
}

return customers.TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()).List<Customer>();
```

Which results in a SQL query similar to (catched by [NHibernate Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof)):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Customer this_
       left outer join Installation installati1_
         on this_.InstallationId = installati1_.Id
       left outer join Address address2_
         on installati1_.AddressId = address2_.Id
WHERE  this_.CountryId = 4
       and installati1_.TypeId = 1
```

When I execute the above SQL query in *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio* it executes in about 5 seconds but returns ~200.000 records. Nevertheless it takes a lot of time to retrieve the *List* when running the code. I've been waiting for 10 minutes without any results. The debug-log indicated that a lot of objects are constructed and initiated because of the object hierarchy. Is there a way to fix this performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but loading and saving 200000 records through any OR mapper is not feasable. 200000 objects will take a lot of memory and time to be created. Depending on what you want to do, loading them in pages or make a update query directly on the database (sp or named query) can fix your performance. Batching can be done by:

```
criteria.SetFirstResult(START).SetMaxResult(PAGESIZE);
```

Comment: There is no saving/updating going on here, only reading data using a *SELECT* query. I need to query all data, as it should be used for an company report. Is there a way to use NHibernate to return the raw data (primitive types) instead of objects?

Comment: Can't you use reporting services or integration services to get the data from the database. These tools are made of these kinds of reports. Or get the data with paging. So you will have more control over the number of objects in memory. criteria.SetFirstResult(START).SetMaxResult(PAGESIZE);

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate Profiler shows two times in the duration column x/y, with x being the time to execute the query and y the time to initialize the objects. The first step is to determine where the problem lies. If the query is slow, get the actual query sent to the database using SQL Profiler (assuming SQL Server) and check its performance in SSMS.

However, I suspect your issue may be the logging level. If you have the logging level set to DEBUG, NHibernate will generate very verbose logs and this will significantly impact performance.

Even if you can get it to perform well with 200000 records that's more than you can display to the user in a meaningful way. You should use paging/filtering to reduce the size of the result set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Debug-logging is not currently enabled. I've made another test, where I made a *.Take(10000)* before the *.List<>()* which results in the following duration in *NHibernate Profiler*: 747 ms / 137202ms. For me this indicates that the issues is about the object initialization.

Comment: Try removing the distinct transformer. 2+ minutes seems unreasonably slow to me.

Comment: Removing the distinct transformer does not make any difference.